Links in tracked mailings munged in 5.72.x?
On upgrading to 5.72 and then 5.72.1 on a Joomla 4.4.3 site the links in Mosaico and standard mailings are munged when tracking is enabled.
For example:
https://domain/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register&Itemid=1392&id=645&reset=1&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}
returns
https://domain/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register&Itemid=1392&id=645&reset=1&cs=061293e03c6ba8ed89adf0f05cabc1c7_1712893020_168&cid=1&id=292
That is, '&id=292' is appended to links (always 292).
This includes plain external links with no tokens:
https://domain/www.facebook.com/pages/fbname/99999999999?v=wall&id=292
These links used in a single email via contact actions work as expected except that the error notification 'Error Expected to find one Event record, but there were zero.' appears on the registration page example (which is probably a red herring & I will put in another post).
